# How to make the view functions work in a scroll view

Tags: ios, uiview, viewwillappear, viewdidunload

Please have a look at the following code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    self.viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
    UIViewController* controller = nil;

    controller = [[aViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"aViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*0, 0, 1024, 768);
    [scrollView1 addSubview:controller.view];   
    [viewControllers addObject:controller];

    controller = [[bViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"bViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*1, 0, 1024, 768);
    [scrollView1 addSubview:controller.view];   
    [viewControllers addObject:controller];

    controller = [[cViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"cViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(1024*2, 0, 1024, 768);
    [scrollView1 addSubview:controller.view];
    [viewControllers addObject:controller];

}
```

I visit the `bViewController` now, and I want to show an alert when I leave the `bViewController`, but the `viewDidUnload` doesn't work.

The `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` doesn't work either.

So which can work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest to show an alert into `scrollViewDidScroll:` method when `scrollView.contentOffset.x < 1024.0f`.

Comment: thanks a lot,another question is how to close the keyboard by using this?

Comment: [textFied resignFirstResponder]; // or searchBar

Comment: hm, there are just only for example. I don't know which control used for showing keyboard.